# How to call an event based on some time input given by user

Tags: jquery, html, events, time

I am making a AC controlling application. For the application to be designed using html, jquery css, i need to add a functionality that user can specify a time and all AC's of the building will automatically be turned off on that time (triggering some event based on the time input given by user).

My question is how to get the system time in html, or jquery and keep on comparing the time entered by the user with the system time to generate the event(call some function).

Comment: Can't get time in html. Get the time through javascript, and then use either setInterval() or setTimeout().

Answer (score 1):

The system time has to be determined by your back-end; i.e. your server. Therefore the time needs to be transfered from your back-end, to your front-end. A common approach to this is by using a asynchronous XHR request, commonly refered to as [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). You mentioned jQuery, which (handy enough) have a function for just that purpose; [ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

So what's the big issue here then? **Timezones.**

You as a client are most often not located in the same timezone as the system (the server) is running. Therefore there is a *time differance*  between you and the server. Suppose I'm in GMT+2 and the server is in GMT+0; that means I'm two hours *ahead* of the server. Now lets say the time is 12:00 my time => 10:00 server time, and I specify the time *15:00*. When is the event actually going to fire?

The answer is that you got to take the time differance into account, and set the properly event time according to that. So in the example scenario, I want the event to fire 15:00 my time, which means the server needs to take **15:00 - 2 hours = 13:00**. Therefore when the server receives this message, it needs to create the event at 13:00 server time (GMT+0).

And then when the time hits 13:00 server time, the AC event can be triggered.